# problem in defining empty list of a class in angular 12

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, class, empty-list

i have a problem defining a empty list of a class in angular.this is my class

```
export class category{
public Id:number;
public Name:string;
constructor(
){}}
```

[image]

i got this error.

An element access expression should take an argument

any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error because you are trying to declare your variable after import statements, not into the class.
You should declare it as below:

```js
//import statements
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
})
export class AppComponent {
  category: category[] = [];
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```